# Python / AJAX / JavaScript - HTML page printing twice during GET

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, cgi

I currently have an issue with my program in which I'm trying to produce live search (much like Google's) using AJAX. At the moment, its based on a list of cities, so when a user types for example "A" in the form, it will show a list of all cities that start with "A". If the user continues to type, for example "Al", it will show a list of all cities that start with "Al" and so on and so forth.

The issue I am having, as the title suggests, is that if I backspace (delete) the text in the form, my python script will send a response to print the HTML page again, thus having two copies of the form.

Below are some image links of what I mean

**Second search:**

http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/1972/city3f.jpg

**Duplicate page:**

http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/5808/city4p.jpg

Below is my code:

python:

```
city = list()

if form.has_key('q'):       
    if len(form['q'].value) > 0:
        for item in city_names: # city_names is a list of cities
            if item.startswith(form['q'].value):
                if not city:
                    city.append(item)
                else:
                    city.append(item)

        print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
        print city

else:
    print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
    print template #html
```

AJAX:

```
function showCity(string)
{
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ // Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{ // Code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("City").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "/cgi-bin/suggestions.py?q="+string, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

How are your events set up?

In the image http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/5808/city4p.jpg, I can see that it's called with `q=` and there's no string to follow so `showCity` is called with an empty string. That makes your script go the print template path.

Can you please show the code where `showCity` gets called?

*Added*

Use `onkeypress`. From a quick test, that doesn't seem to register the backspace at all. Other than that you need to filter the backspace or at least check if the string has content.

Comment: the showCity function is in my html code, <input type="text" onkeyup="showCity(this.value)"></submit>